# Can't find MySQL on MAC

Tags: mysql, macos

I just installed MySQL on my Mac and I can't find usr/local/mysql on my machine.  I cd to the home directory but when I type in cd usr I can't see it and I am unable to determine if MySQL was installed.

How can I find the installation?

Comment: `locate mysql`/`whereis ...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terminal window:

> cd /usr

To view hidden folders in Finder:

1. Open Terminal found in `Finder > Applications > Utilities`
2. In `Terminal`, paste the following:

   `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`
3. Press return.
4. Hold the `Option/alt` key,
5. Then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and select `Relaunch`

Answer (score 4):

go to terminal

type `cd /usr/local`
you will find your mysql folder